# Remove remote host from Visual Studio Code Remote Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a list of remote hosts in Visual Studio Code.

How do I remove the entries that are not valid anymore ?

[image]

Comment: By editing `.ssh/config` file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957203/how-do-we-remove-ssh-targets-from-remote-explorer

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove or edit remote hosts by editing the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Below is the contents of a `~/.ssh/config` file with four remote host entries. To delete entries "that are not valid anymore", delete the full indented block:

```
Host 192.168.0.22
  HostName 192.168.0.22
  User sq

Host 192.168.0.43
  HostName 192.168.0.43
  User vx

Host 192.168.0.22
  HostName 192.168.0.22
  User ha

Host homeassistant.local
  HostName homeassistant.local
  Port 8123
  User ha
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: Can you provide further instructions on what in that file needs to be modified?